# How do i create a nested list in Python

Tags: python, variable-assignment

i have this empty list and i would like to another list inside the main one
here's the error that I'm getting :

```py
Classroom = []

n = int(input("give me the numbers of the students : "))

for i in range(n) :
    name = input("give me the name of the student : ")
    score = float(input("give me the score of the student : "))
    Classroom.append(list())
    Classroom[i][0] = name
    Classroom[i][1] = score

print(Classroom)
```

and this is the error I'm getting

```py
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: `Classroom[i]` has no element. So accessing `Classroom[i][0]` or `Classroom[i][1]` will throw this error. Maybe you want to `append()`

Comment: This is nothing to do with the nesting, you can't assign to _any_ list index out of bounds. `Classroom.append([name, score])`? `Classroom[i].append(name)`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Classroom = []

n = int(input("give me the numbers of the students : "))

for i in range(n) :
    name = input("give me the name of the student : ")
    score = float(input("give me the score of the student : "))
    l=[]
    Classroom.append(l)
    Classroom[i].append(name)
    Classroom[i].append(score)

print(Classroom)
```

The error was you were trying to assign a list element which is not existing, use append to add the name and score

Comment: problem solved , thank you